# Bash regex to grab subdomain from list of urls

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I have a file which contains list of URLs and I want to grab the subdomains from them.

List of URLs are:

```
https://www.google.com [match www]
https://www.something.random-name.domain.com [match www, something, and random-name]
https://facebook.com [don't match anything]
http://test.prod-op.bpo.yahoo.com [match test, prod-op and bpo]
```

I've been using the "sed" command to ditch https and http prefix and then using "awk "command to get the subdomains but the problem is I can only match the first subdomain for example:
`https://www.something.random-name.domain.com`

In the above example my approach would only match "www" But I want it to match "www" along with "something" and "random-name".

Input would be:

```
https://www.google.com 
https://www.something.random-name.domain.com 
https://facebook.com
http://test.prod-op.bpo.yahoo.com
```

Output would be:

```
www
www something random-name
null
test prod-op bpo
```

Kindly, explain me what shall be done so that I could match and extract the subdomains.

Thank you!

Comment: `cat domainnames | sed -E 's/^\s*.*:\/\///g' | awk -F"." '{print $1}' `This is what I had been using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is your example file, and how to use sed to get all subdomains:

```
$ cat test.txt
https://www.google.com
https://www.something.random-name.domain.com
https://facebook.com
http://test.prod-op.bpo.yahoo.com
$ cat test.txt | sed -e 's/https*:\/\///; s/\.*[^\.]*\.[^\.]*$//; s/^$/null/; s/\./ /g'
www
www something random-name
null
test prod-op bpo
$
```

Explanation:

- `s/https*:\/\///;` - remove protocol
- `s/\.*[^\.]*\.[^\.]*$//;` - remove domain name and TLD
- `s/^$/null/;` - change an empty line to `null`
- `s/\./ /g` - change all dots to space

Answer (score 2):

With two **GNU** `awk`:

```
awk -F '/' '{$0=$NF}1' file | awk -F '.' '{NF=NF-2}; NF<1{$0="null"}1'
```

> `$NF`: contains last column

> `NF=NF-2`: Removes the last two columns from current row

Output:

```
www
www something random-name
null
test prod-op bpo
```

---

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Answer (score 1):

This `awk` can do it in a single command:

```sh
awk -F. '{gsub(/^https?:\/\/|\.?[^.]+\.[^.]+$/, ""); $1=$1; print (/./ ? $0 : "null")}' file

www
www something random-name
null
test prod-op bpo
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's#^https?://(.*)(\.[^.]+){2}#\1#;y/./ /;t;cnull' file
```

Pattern match on the url, removing everything but the required section.

Manipulate the section into the required format and print the result.

Otherwise, change the existing line to `null`.